# Deleting example posts causing errors in build_site()

Tags: r, blogdown

I am building my site with blogdown and the academic theme for Hugo and everything is going well. However, when I delete example posts files from the content/posts folder, errors appear in build_site ().

For example, if I delete the widgets.md file (an example post) and use build_site (), I get

```
blogdown::build_site()
Started building sites ...
Built site for language en:
0 draft content
0 future content
0 expired content
9 regular pages created
14 other pages created
0 non-page files copied
1 paginator pages created
0 tags created
0 categories created
1 publication_types created
ERROR 2017/08/22 10:21:49 error processing shortcode "_internal/shortcodes/ref.html" for page "post\getting-started.md": template: _internal/shortcodes/ref.html:1:73: executing "_internal/shortcodes/ref.html" at <ref .Page (.Get 0)>: error calling ref: No page found with path or logical name "post/widgets.md".
```

Am I forgetting to delete some reference to the deleted file?

Comment: I am using the two repositories approach proposed in [Building a Blog with Blogdown and GitHub](https://tclavelle.github.io/blog/blogdown_github/).

Answer (score 2):

In your example post `content/post/getting-started.md`, there must be a Hugo shortcode `{{< ref "post/widgets.md" >}}`. Delete it if you do not understand it.

That example post was [from the hugo-academic theme](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/blob/master/exampleSite/content/post/getting-started.md), and there are more shortcodes in the post. If you have deleted the Markdown files referenced by the `ref` shortcode, you should delete the shortcodes, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and Blogdown! However, I still have problems deleting the file.

My post example was `widgets.md`, the only shortcode I identified was 

```{{% Alert note%}}
By default, publications will be...
{{% / Alert%}}
```
I can not identify which file was referenced by the shortcode `{{% alert note%}}`!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this particular theme, but I don't really recommend you to delete files before you figure out what they do.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, I will continue analyzing the issue.

Comment: The problem disappears after deleting all the example posts, thank you for your attention. Tyler Clavelle suggested this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem disappears after deleting all the example posts.